# "The system cannot find the file specified" error in windows 10 when deleting a disk partition

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning

I'm trying to delete a partition occupied by CentOS (to reinstall over it) using Windows 10's Disk Management utility on a dual boot laptop, but the 'Delete Volume' operation on this partition is giving an error instead (images attached below).  I have also tried `DiskPart`, which gives the same `The system cannot find the file specified`.

Disk Management Utility Steps: [Delete Volume Operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgA1K.png) > [Bridge Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwi77.png) > Error
[image: Error]

`DiskPart` Steps:

- `list disk` > `select disk 0` > `list partition` > `select partition 6` > `delete partition` outputs:

  ```
  DiskPart has encountered an error: The system cannot find the file specified.
  See the System Event Log for more information.
  ```

Comment: Since you intend to reinstall the same system, you could boot from a CentOS DVD (or a bootable USB) and format the partition before starting the installation

Comment: What does the Event Log say?  WinX menu > Event Viewer

Comment: I agree with @spike_66.  Who cares why it won't work?.. just use the partition manager built into the CentOS installer.  If it can't do the job either, you will at least get an error from a different point of view.

Comment: Apparently, windows wasn't able to do delete partition of linux file system ... I agree with @spike_66 and have partitioned using system rescue cd live cd then reinstalled ubuntu.